# Application Approval

Tags: marketing-cloud, hubexchange

I have a hub exchange application in development and would like to have it approved. What are the steps to do so? I have not found any documentation for this.

Answer (score 0):

We followed [this six step process](http://pages.exacttarget.com/HubExchangePartners/become-a-partner/) for our app to be listed on HubExchange. However, I note that the enrollment form has now been deactivated — apparently they are not accepting new partners at this time. You might want to drop an email to HubExchange[at]exacttarget.com to enquire what the program status is. This is a monitored email account (or at least, it was when I last used it).